# Debugging Audio DAC. Got no output. (Schematic, Artwork included)

Tags: esp32, dac

I have my custom board designed and got no output from DAC. (I connected AMP - Speaker but got no sound)

DAC: [PCM5102APWR](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Digital-To-Analog-Converters-DACs_Texas-Instruments-PCM5102APWR_C107671.html) ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5100a.pdf?ts=1689219104710&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Faudio-ic%252Fconverters%252Fdac%252Fproducts.html))

I am using [ESP32­-PICO-­MINI-­02](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-mini-02_datasheet_en.pdf) to output sound to I2S.

Thank you for your help.

[image: dac]
[image: esp]
[image: pcb1]
[image: pcb2]

Comment: I don't think VNEG cap is correctly drawn, but it might not the the reason why it does not work. What sampling rate and bit clock rate are you using, and have you verified with a scope that ESP outputs correct clocks and there is data?

Comment: @Justme
 Thank you for a comment. Yes I should definitely check with the scope. 
By the way, I found that C23 in my schematic is 2.2nF, but the typical application schematic in the datasheet is 2.2uF. Do you think this can be the reason why it does not work?

Comment: Of course it can be. The charge pump cap is off by a factor of 1000 then.

Answer (score 3):

Change charge pump capacitor 2.2uF from 2.2nF solved the issue.